# Como usar uma imagem (ou caractere) de borda via CSS?

Tags: html, css, html5, css3, twitter-bootstrap

Eu tenho uma tag `<p>` com texto dentro que eu gostaria de usar os caracteres de chaves `[ ]` como borda para esse texto.

Código:

```css
.indicacoes {
font-family: 'AmaticBold';
font-size: 40px;
margin-top: 30px;
text-align: center; }
```

```html
<div class="container">
        <div class="texto-principal">
            <p id="borderimg" class="indicacoes">texto de teste! <br>
                TEXTO TEXTO TEXTO TEXTO. <br>
                TEXTO TEXTO TEXTO.</p>
        </div>
</div>
```

O objetivo é ficar como na imagem em anexo:
[image: Imagem de exemplo]

Comment: O texto ali sempre vai ter no máximo 3 linhas? Pode ser com SVG?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fiz um modelo usando *pseudo-elemento* mesmo, pois assim eu consigo controlar melhor o contorno e as curvaturas. Sei que não ficou exatamente igual, mas as vezes te atende...

Não precisei mexer em nada no seu HTML, apenas no box onde o texto está dentro eu crie um `::before` e `::after` Essas "chaves" `[ ]` sempre vão ter a altura do conteúdo, então não importa se tem muito ou pouco texto, as "chaves" sempre vão se ajustar com o conteúdo.

O macete aqui foi construir um retângulo de cada lado do box do texto e remover a borda de dentro desse quadrado, para deixa arredondado os cantos é só usar `border-radius`. Porém como falei no início não fica exatamente igual a imagem

```css
.indicacoes {
    font-family: 'AmaticBold';
    font-size: 40px;
    margin-top: 30px;
    text-align: center; 
}
.texto-principal {
    padding: 1rem;
    width: 50%;
    margin: 1rem auto;
    position: relative;
}
.texto-principal::after,
.texto-principal::before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 4em;
    height: 100%;
    border: .5em solid currentColor;
    border-radius: .5em;
}
.texto-principal::after {
    left: 0;
    border-right: 0;
}
.texto-principal::before {
    right: 0;
    border-left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="texto-principal">
        <p id="borderimg" class="indicacoes">
            texto de teste! <br>
            TEXTO TEXTO TEXTO TEXTO. <br>
            TEXTO TEXTO TEXTO.
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta. Mesmo que o resultado final não tenha ficado como a imagem, me ajudou muito! Agradeço pela ajuda.

Comment: @Thomaz1593 legal jovem, que bom que te ajudou ai. Boa sorte com o projeto!

Answer (score 0):

Como diz [esta resposta do SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41807110/3388148) você pode desenhar as chaves sem o uso de qualquer pseudo elemento em CSS puro.

**Passos:**

- Crie um elemento como `<div` ou `span` e utilize `inline-block` para que o tamanho seja dependente do conteúdo;
- Aplique as bordas na direita e esquerda;
- Use `linear-gradient()` para criar 4 imagens de fundo com altura e largura específicas e desenhe em cada canto da caixa com `background-position`. A propriedade `height` do `background-size` deve ser igual a espessura da borda esquerda.

```css
div.chaves {
  background-image: linear-gradient(#000000, #000000),
                    linear-gradient(#000000, #000000),
                    linear-gradient(#000000, #000000),
                    linear-gradient(#000000, #000000);
  border: solid #000000;

  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  /* O segundo valor deve ser igual à largura das bordas */
  background-size: 8px 4px;
  border-width: 0 4px;
  background-position: top left, top right, bottom left, bottom right;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div style="display: flex; justify-content: center; padding-top: 50px;">
  <div style="width: 40%;">
    <div class="chaves">
      <p id="borderimg" class="indicacoes">
        texto de teste! <br> TEXTO TEXTO TEXTO TEXTO. <br> TEXTO TEXTO TEXTO.
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta. Ela foi muito útil!